# Landing Page default URL parameters

Tags: docusignapi

Is there a way to customize/suppress the default URL parameters (env, pf, r) sent with the DocuSign insession landing pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't believe it's possible to customize or suppress those parameters.